# Node.js executing mysql query after receiving message from mqtt broker

Tags: mysql, node.js, mqtt

I have a node.js file that subscribes to a topic and upon receiving a published message scans a local mysql db for the most recent entry in a variable named "command".  Command values will trigger various responses, but I have left this portion out since my issue is before this.

My mysql query appears to be giving me errors.  I am trying to look for the most recent entry of the command column and assign the value to a var command.  I thought this code would do the trick:

```
var sql = 'SELECT command FROM motoron2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        console.log(result);
        var command = result[1];
        console.log(command);
```

[image: phpmyadmin]
But I am getting the following response which seems to indicate an error in the mysql query:

```
user@server.domain [bin]# node motorlistener.js
Connected to MYSQL!
Connected to Broker!
{"pulse":1}
1
/home/user/etc/domain/bin/motorlistener.js:62
    console.log(result);
                ^

ReferenceError: result is not defined
    at MqttClient.<anonymous> (/home/user/etc/domain/bin/motorlistener.js:62:17)
    at MqttClient.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at MqttClient._handlePublish (/home/user/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:1277:12)
    at MqttClient._handlePacket (/home/user/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:410:12)
    at work (/home/user/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:321:12)
    at Writable.writable._write (/home/user/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:335:5)
    at doWrite (/home/user/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:409:139)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/user/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:398:5)
    at Writable.write (/home/user/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:307:11)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:718:22)
```

The full code is below, but does anyone know what is causing this error?

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//setup
var mqtt    = require('mqtt'); //for client use
const fs = require('fs');
var caFile = fs.readFileSync("/home/user/etc/domain/bin/ca.crt");
var topic = "heartbeat";
var mysql      = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'myuser',
  password : 'mypass',
  database : 'mydb'
});

var options={
    port:8883,
    clientId:"yo",
    username:"myuser2",
    password:"mypassw",
    protocol: 'mqtts',
    clean:true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    retain:false, 
    ca:caFile
};


var client  = mqtt.connect("http://dns.org",options);

//mqtt connection dialog
client.on("connect",function(){
    console.log("Connected to Broker!");
    client.subscribe(topic, {qos:1});
});

//mqtt connection handle errors
client.on("error",function(error){
    console.log("Broker Connection Error");
    process.exit(1);
});

//database connection
con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected to MYSQL!");
});

//handle incoming messages from broker
client.on('message',function(topic, message, packet){
    var raw = ""+message;
    console.log(raw);
    var obj = JSON.parse(raw);
    var pulse = obj.pulse; 
    console.log(pulse);
    
    var sql = 'SELECT command FROM motoron2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    console.log(result);
    var command = result[1];
    console.log(command);
    
    if (command == 1) {
        console.log("command=1");
    }
    else {
        console.log("command not equal to 0");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am getting the following response which seems to indicate an error in the mysql query

That's not an error in your MySQL query. It's a null reference error because you're trying to use `result` outside the callback.

Changing your code to this will work:

```
var sql = 'SELECT command FROM motoron2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
   if (err) { 
       throw err; 
   }
   // access result inside the callback
   console.log(result);
   var command = result[0];
   console.log(command);
});
```

Depending on your environment you may be able to re-write your code using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await) to reduce the nested scopes.

To do so, you'd need to turn your callback into a promise and then you can await it, like so:

```
let sql = 'SELECT command FROM motoron2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';

// 1 -- we turn the query into a promise 
const queryPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  con.query(sql, function (queryError, queryResult) {
    if (queryError) { 
       reject(queryError); 
    }
    resolve(queryResult);
  });
});

try {
  // 2 -- we can now await the promise; note the await
  let result = await queryPromise;

  // 3 -- now we can use the result as if it executed synchronously
  console.log(result);
  let command = result[0];
  console.log(command);
} catch(err) {
  // we can catch query errors and handle them here
}
```

Putting it all together, you should be able to change the on message event handler to an async function in order to take advantage of the async/await pattern as shown above:

```
client.on('message', async function(topic, message, packet) {
    
    /* .. you can use await here .. */
    
});
```

Comment: For the first block of replacement code suggested I am seeing good results except that the `console.log(command)` is showing as `undefined`.  While the console.log(result) is `[ RowDataPacket { command: 1 } ]`

Comment: Oh, looks like the index is off by one -- should be `result[0]`

Comment: looks like that gives me the same thing as `console.log(result)` in my previous comment.  How can I make `console.log(command)` print a 1?

Comment: looks like the result is an object that has a command parameter, try `console.log(command.command);`

Comment: you were right I actually was trying result.command before this comment without success so I am very glad you commented this

Answer (score 1):

All above code from @Mike Dinescu works perfectly fine. Just dont forget on the end to close the connection!

Else the runner will hangs after tests have finished.

the full solution:

```
async function mySqlConnect(dbquery) {
    const conn = mysql.createPool({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,  
      user: 'test',
      password: 'test',
      database: 'test'
    }, { debug: true });
    
    // 1 -- we turn the query into a promise 
const queryPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  conn.query(dbquery, function (queryError, queryResult) {
    if (queryError) { 
       reject(queryError); 
    }
    resolve(queryResult);
  });
});

try {
  // 2 -- we can now await the promise; note the await
  let result = await queryPromise;

  // 3 -- now we can use the result as if it executed synchronously
  //console.log(result);
  let command = await result[0];
  //console.log(command);
  return command;
} catch(err) {

}

finally{
  conn.end(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('error:' + err.message);
    }
    //console.log('Close the database connection.');
  });
}
  
}
```